# can app decide to show alert based on user dictionary when receiving a push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible when you receive a push notification to somehow have your application decide whether or not to show the AlertView indicating you received a push notification?

Or does the OS just automatically control this and not let you have any control in this?

I would like to receive some notification to my app and then let my app decide based on some data in the dictionary that is passed in with [didReceiveRemoteNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveRemoteNotification%3a), whether or not to show the Alert or some user visible notification?  Is this possible in ANY way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control appearance of `UIAlertView` about Push through your application. But may be server could: try to send Push-notification w/o `alert` information.

Tell me, please, how it works.
TY

Answer (score 0):

It's 17 days until it's 10 years since this question was asked. Now, you can, since <kbd>iOS 10.0</kbd>`.

I just wrote an answer to [how to get the userInfo in other delegate methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68971418/7365866). In your specific case, you want to implement the [userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter).

Get the `userInfo` dictionary in that delegate method by using `notification.request.content.userInfo`. If you set a key/value such as `foregroundNotification: true` in the `data` payload passed to APNs, your device can see that here.

All you have to do is:

```swift
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
if let foregroundNotification = userInfo["foregroundNotification"] as? Bool, foregroundNotification == true {
    completionHandler([.banner])
}
```

---

### More advanced handling (sound, supporting iOS 10+, including deprecations)

Bear in mind `alert` has been deprecated in iOS 14, and you may want to add iOS version checks, sound, list.

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    var options: UNNotificationPresentationOptions = []
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    if let foregroundSound = userInfo["foregroundSound"] as? Bool, foregroundSound == true {
        options.insert(.sound)
    }
    
    if let foregroundBadge = userInfo["foregroundBadge"] as? Bool, foregroundBadge == true {
        options.insert(.badge)
    }
    
    if let foregroundList = userInfo["foregroundList"] as? Bool, foregroundList == true {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            options.insert(.list)
        }
    }
    
    if let foregroundNotification = userInfo["foregroundNotification"] as? Bool, foregroundNotification == true {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            options.insert(.banner)
        } else {
            options.insert(.alert)
        }
    }
    
    completionHandler(options)
}
```