# How to get userInfo from Apple Push Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

My enterprise app is using Apple Push Notifications, and it works fine under most circumstances. What I would like to do is get the user information from a notification in a method other than the `userDidRespondToPush`.

If there is a notification waiting, the system puts a badge on the icon on the iPhone's home screen. If a user responds to the notification itself, the app will trigger `userRespondsToPush`. But if the user doesn't swipe the notification and starts the app normally, by tapping on the app's icon with a badge showing, I'd like to have the app respond as if the user did swipe the notification. That means I would need to get the `userInfo` in a method other than `userDidRespondToPush` so the app will know what information to show the user.

Push Notifications is pretty new to me, but I've had some pretty good luck getting it working. I just need this one little feature to work.

Answer (score 1):

If your application supports iOS 10 and above, then you should be able to retrieve pending notifications using the `UNUserNotificationCenter` class.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotificationRequest *> * _Nonnull requests) {
        for (UNNotificationRequest *request in requests) {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = request.content.userInfo;
            NSLog(@"push user info: %@", userInfo);
            // Handle the payload here.
        }
    }];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I was looking at `UNUserNotificationCenter` but I couldn't get it to work. It's obviously more complicated than I had expected. I'll try it out and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Try pasting the code in your AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method and see if the user info payload objects are being logged in the lldb console. I've used this API in the past and the implementation is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to know the app launched from RemoteNotifiication Or started normally from app icon.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    return YES;
}
```

if remote Notification exists, means app started from RemoteNotification, otherwise NO.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short answer to a similar question: how to get the `userInfo` in other delegate methods, other than `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. It depends on your **delegate method**, but basically you have to dig it out:

- If you have **notification**: `notification.request.content.userInfo`. This is the case for [`userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter)
- If you have **response**: `response.notification.request.content.userInfo`. This is the case for [`userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension/1845197-didreceivenotificationresponse)
- If you have **userInfo**: you've already got it.

You should either have `notification`, `response` or `userInfo` passed to you, depending on which delegate method is called.

Once you can get `userInfo`, you can do any logic you want in these delegate methods based on the dictionary your server sent you.